# using populate plugin with ajaxSubmit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
 $("#searchbutton").live('click', function() {
            $("#searchform").ajaxSubmit({
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#registrationform').populate(data);
                },
                resetForm: true
            });
        });
```

I have this piece of code that takes input from a form and return values in JSON format to be use by a populate plugin. However when i click submit i get "Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: # "

Can anyone tell what I may need to do to resolve this error?

Comment: does is make the `ajaxSubmit`? Also, `live` is deprecated as of `jquery1.7` . Use `$("document").on('click', '#searchbutton', function()`

Comment: That doesn't seem to solve the problem...

Comment: i know it wouldnt. My question was, does the `ajaxSubmit` happen? If you do an `alert(data)` in `success`, do you get a response?

Comment: Yes I do. The ajaxSubmit works. If I the populate plugin by itself also, that works fine. using them together, that's when i get the problem. when i alert data, i get my JSON String.. eg {id: 1,firstName: Dave} plugin url: http://www.keyframesandcode.com/resources/javascript/jQuery/demos/populate-demo.html

Comment: should it not be ` {id: 1,firstName: 'Dave'} ` ?

Comment: yes, typo on my part. sorry. I think the error is happening with /*! jQuery v1.7.2 jquery.com

Comment: and does registrationform have `id` and `firstName` fields? Update jQuery and change `live` to `on`

Comment: updating jquery doesn't seem to solve the problem. and yes registration form has id and firstName fields